# Can you give AWS IAM user permissions to create CloudFront keypairs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, key, amazon-cloudfront, key-pair

I know what the documentation says:

> **Important**
>   IAM users can't create CloudFront key pairs. You must log in using root credentials to create key pairs.

But I what to know is this restriction a permission based. Can you give that permission to IAM user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the person paying the bills is privileged only to do that. IAM users cannot have these privileges even if they have full admin access.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answer I was looking for.